# groovy and grails - wrong environment variable in MAC

Tags: macos, grails, groovy, osx-mountain-lion, setenv

I am trying to setup grail in mac os 10.8.3

- I've downloaded and installed groovy.
- Then, I downloaded grails 2.2.2 and unzipped it.
- I ran

sudo nano launchd.conf

- and added the location of grails:

setenv GRAILS_HOME /Users/hdeus/Documents/Code/grails-2.2.2

- saved the file. When I run

echo $GRAILS_HOME

- I get:

/Users/hdeus/.gvm/grails/current

Which, I suspect, is the env var setup by Groovy automatically (which is overlapping the one that I setup!) - but there is nothing in that folder so grails won't work! Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: `/Users/hdeus/.gvm/grails/current` means that it was set up by GVM tool http://gvmtool.net/ was it  not? Did you install grails before using this tool?

Comment: As mentioned by @ivarPrudnikov, it is set by gvmtool. gvmtool scripts are sourced from your tcshrc or bashrc/bash_profile (depending on your shell). Remove the line sourcing the gvm script and your issue will go away...

Answer (score 2):

If you have the gvm tool set up which is looks like you do it is much easier to download and install grails via that tool

```
gvm use grails 2.2.2
```

The gvm tool is great for managing the different versions of grails.

Answer (score 0):

use export GRAILS_HOME instead:

`GRAILS_HOME=/Users/hdeus/Documents/Code/grails-2.2.2`

export GRAILS_HOME

echo $GRAILS_HOME

/Users/hdeus/Documents/Code/grails-2.2.2